# Get list element when HTML Parsing

Tags: c#, html, html-parsing, html-agility-pack, html-parser

I have a piece of HTML like this :

```
<li class="myclass">
            <ul class="myclass2">
                <li><span>Name1</span><span>Value1</span></li><li><span>Name2</span><span>Value2</span></li><li><span>Name3</span><span>Value3</span></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

I'm trying to parse this HTML like this using HTML Agility Pack :

```
var values = mydetails.DocumentNode.QuerySelector(".myclass").QuerySelector("ul").InnerHtml;
```

This gives me this part :

```
<li><span>Name1</span><span>Value1</span></li><li><span>Name2</span><span>Value2</span></li><li><span>Name3</span><span>Value3</span></li>
```

But I don't know how to go further, I need Names and Values but I don't know how to get them. Can you show me a way to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give your items an html-id, then it should be very easy to get this element in javascript. I don't know your framework, but in others this is very easy, for example in jQuery: `$("#id")`

Comment: Those items don't have an id and I can't give them an id.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without id?

Comment: you could try getChild(). If you use this function on the ul, it gives you an array. The first item would then be `....QuerySelector("ul").getChild[0]...`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Regular expression to get values from all the  tags

```
public void ProcessSpans(string inputHTML)
{
    string pattern = @"<span([^>]*)class=\""(\w+)\""([^>]*)>(.*)<\/span>";
    RegexOptions regexOptions = RegexOptions.Multiline;
    Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, regexOptions);
    var matches = regex.Matches(inputHTML);
    //Process the matches with your logic. 
}
```

Then call the method as such

```
var values = mydetails.DocumentNode.QuerySelector(".myclass").QuerySelector("ul").InnerHtml;
ProcessSpans(values);
```